# Can't get reactive var from helper in meteor js

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to write the value of a reactive var to a meteor template:

```
Template.form.rendered = function() {
    this.color = new ReactiveVar();
    this.color.set('#333555');
};
```

and then I've defined a "currentColor" helper to use in the template to print the color: {{currentColor}}

```
Template.form.helpers({
    currentColor: fuction() {
        return Template.instance().color.get();
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work;
so I've tried to add a couple of console.log:

```
Template.form.helpers({
    currentColor: fuction() {
        console.log(Template.instance());
        console.log(Template.instance().color);
    }
});
```

The strange thing is that the first console log shows a Blaze.TemplateInstance with the color property:

```
Blaze.TemplateInstance {...}
    color: ReactiveVar
        curValue: "#333555"
        dep: Tracker.Dependency
        equalsFunc: undefined
    ...
```

but the second log is "undefined";
Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should place the `ReactiveVar` definition in your `template.created()` function, not the `template.rendered()` function.

Comment: Also, there's a typo in 'fuction' in Cereal Killer's example.